# Usage differences between "than", "to", and "over"

Tags: differences, prepositions, conjunctions

I understand that **than**, **rather than**, **over** and **to** are used to compare things. How ever I am not sure when to use those for specific scenarios. Are these interchangeable?

Consider the sentence below:

> Peter’s performance is better than Jim’s.

Can I write this as:

> Peter’s performance is better rather than Jim’s.
>    Peter’s performance is better to Jim’s.
>    Peter’s performance is better above Jim’s.

I personally feel among the above four sentences the last 2 seem awkward (I might be wrong also). However I am curious to know which of the words are most suitable to which cases?

And my focus here is not on **Better**. Rather it is on when we use 'to' for comparison? And when we use 'over' comparison? And when we use the adverb 'rather' before 'than' in a comparison. I would like to know the line which is drawn between those.

Comment: @Regdwight: Thank you. How ever my focus is not on _prefer_. It is on _to_ and _than_. Hence I have improved my question. Can you consider to reopen the question. If not please let me know the reason.

Comment: I think all three sentences sounds awkward. However, you can say "The news gets better rather than worse." - "It's better to do ...". I can't think of any sentence with "better above" but perhaps it's possible though.

Comment: @Ramesh - the linked question is about *to, than* and *over* as well

Comment: @Matt Эллен: Well, I have gone through all the answers. The focus is more on _prefer_ rather than _"to"_,_"than"_ and _"over"_. There is some clarity when we have to use "over". But it is limited. Even after reading the answers it is not answering my question when to use "to" , when to use "than", when to use "over" completely?

Comment: Ramesh, one never uses *to*, *above* or *over* with *better*, only *than*: *X is better than Y*. And *rather* is an adverb: *I would rather do X*. - May I invite you to visit and support the proposed [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) site, intended to deal with such fundamental questions?

Comment: @StoneyB: To a first approximation, I'm sure that's all so. But people do actually *say* ["That's rather better"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that's+rather+better%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) Sometimes *"rather"* is an intensifier *rather than* an element forming part of a comparative construction (like this! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Well, I'm not altogether clear what we've decided an adverb is; but whatever it is, *rather* is that when it qualifies/modifies/is an adjunct to *better*. And *rather better* is something different from *better rather*. Now: if we thought OP's second sentence represented *Peter's performance is [the] better, **rather than [=not]** Jim's* there might be room for an interesting discussion.

Comment: @StoneyB: You certainly won't find me laying down the law about what's an adverb and what isn't. Anyway, it's all down to *usage in context* in the end. I think all I meant was that when paired with *than*, *rather* works somewhat differently (call it a *conjunction*, whatever). But it can just be a standalone intensifier with (to me) quite a different sense (I should refrain from saying that's rather a clumsy way of putting it! :).

Comment: @StoneyB: Thanks for your explanation and invitation too. My focus here is not on Better. I would like to know when we use each of those individually in the context of comparision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of your four sentences, only the first is entirely acceptable as it stands. The rest are little ambiguous; they *may* represent acceptable elliptical constructions; but they *cannot* be used to represent the same meaning as the first.

I’ll strip out the specific words and use abstract *X* and *Y* for the nouns and abstract *A* for the positive adjective, with *A-er* as its comparative grade. *A-ness* is the quality expressed by A.

> 1. X is A-er than Y.
> 2. <sup>?</sup>X is A-er rather than Y.
> 3. <sup>?</sup>X is A-er to Y.
> 4. <sup>?</sup>X is A-er above Y.

Sentence 1 states that X has more A-ness than Y has.

*Rather than* means *instead of* or *and not* or *in preference to*, and Sentence 2 may be parsed a couple of different ways. Most simply, it claims that X, *and not* Y, has more A-ness **than something else**—call it Z. Under this parsing the sentence is an elliptical form of

> 2a. X, rather than Y, is A-er [than Z]. (Note that we have to move the *rather than* phrase; if we left it at the end it would mean *It is Y, rather than Z, which X is A-er than*.)

However, it is possible that X and Y are being compared to each other, as in Sentence 1. In that case, the sentence would be parsed as an elliptical form of

> 2b. X is A-er [than Y], rather than Y [being A-er than X].

In both cases, however, it is the construction *A-er than* which performs the comparison; *rather than* heads an adverbial phrase which modifies the core statement.

The *rather than* construction can also be used to compare two verbal phrases instead of two nouns, and in this case the construction may be split:

> 2c. I would rather do X than [do] Y.  eg, I would rather eat ice cream than broccoli.
>   2d. I would rather V<sub>X</sub> than V<sub>Y</sub>. eg, I would rather eat ice cream than be boiled in oil.

In Sentence 3, *to* is a preposition which plays no part in a comparison. It may, however, be a component of a gradable “phrasal adjective” (that’s a term I just made up) like *close to*. If that phrasal adjective exists, the sentence could be parsed in two ways, as two different ellipses:

> 3a. X is *A-er to* Y [than X is to Z]. eg New York is closer to Washington than Chicago.
>   3b. X is *A-er to* Y [than Z is to Y]. eg New York is closer to Washington than Boston.

(But the phrasal adjective *better to* is not current in English, so as it stands your own sentence is not acceptable.)

The *to* might also be used with the *-ed* participle of a verb which performs a comparison; *to* then would be either the head of a prepositional phrase modifying the verb or a prepositional component of a phrasal main verb—it’s often hard to draw the line between these. In any case, the participle would be in positive form, not comparative, since the comparative sense would be expressed lexically:

> 3c. X is *V-d to* Y. eg New York is *preferred to* Washington.

In Sentence 4, *above* works the same way; I can’t offhand think of a phrasal adjective with *above*, but here’s a use with a participle:

> 4a. X is *V-d above* Y. eg New York is *ranked above* Washington.

But a comparison employing a comparative-grade adjective almost always implies the construction with *than* in your Sentence 1; so Sentences 3 and 4 are unacceptable with *better* or with any other *A-er* form which does not form a phrasal adjective with the preposition.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a native speaker of English, and you are curious about the rhyme or reason in the formation of English comparative constructions, consider reading [Stassen's contribution](http://wals.info/chapter/121) to the World Atlas of Language Structures on the topic of comparative constructions.

All languages have means for expressing that an entity X possesses a given property in greater degree than an entity Y. Following Stassen's terminology, call X the comparee, and call Y the standard of comparison.

You will notice from Stassen's article that in many languages the standard of comparison is encoded with a locative expression, and that in many languages the standard of comparison is modified by a word translatable as "surpass." From experience with your native language, then, it might seem reasonable to form a comparative construction as `X is [property] past/above/beyond X`.

In English, though, the standard of comparison is almost invariably marked with the preposition `than`. This is just an idiosyncratic fact about the language that will have to be memorized.

English also has a kind of "standardless" construction, such as:

> Thomas is rather tall.

which means that when compared to the average person, Thomas is usually taller.
There is also a kind of construction which can take on comparative meaning when used with verbs such as *like, prefer, admire*.

> Thomas likes bread rather than pasta.

(i.e., Thomas likes bread more than he likes pasta.) When used with other verbs, however, *rather than* is best understood to mean *instead of*, e.g.,

> Thomas killed a bear rather than a tiger.

Comparatives formed with *rather* either do not have a standard of comparison, or are restricted to a particular subset of verbs, so they should not be treated as being part of the main strategy for forming comparatives.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is just fine as-is:

> Peter’s performance is better than Jim’s.

The second sentence makes no sense, because "better rather" isn't a valid construct. However, that could be changed with punctuation:

> Peter’s performance is better, rather than Jim’s.

Do you see the slight shift in meaning? In the first sentence, I'm saying Peter's performance is better, but, in the second, I'm also refuting the assertion that Jim's performance is better.

The third sentence simply uses the wrong preposition. I can't imagine saying that in any context.  That's not saying that "better to" is never used; [Tennyson](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/62650.html) used it:

> ’Tis better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all

but, in that cause, "to" doesn't go with "better", it goes with "have." "Better" still goes with "than" in that sentence, as it could be reworded like this:

> Loving and losing is better than not loving at all.

As for the fourth sentence, I don't like "better above" much more than "better rather." I suppose one could say:

> Peter's performance is above Jim's.

But, in that case, *above* does the comparitive work, so there's no need to include "better" or "better than".

In summary, it's better to stick with *than* when making comparisons between Peter and Jim (and just about anything else) than to try to force some other word into the construct.

---

<sup>I do hope you've supported [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners); this would be a good question over there.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. I used Grammarly (Keyboard on Android)  to find errors in these sentences. It says they are correct. I used bracket to indicate the correction it suggested.

> Robin prefers literature over science

> Robin prefers literature more to (than) science

> Robin prefers literature to science

> I like death more than dishonor

> I prefer death to dishonor

> I like death over dishonor

Comment: You should explain how these examples answer the question.